# Problem on definition of large deviation principle

Tags: pr.probability, large-deviations

As in many classic textbooks, the definition of large deviation principle is as follows:

**$\{\mu_n\}$ has LDP with speed $a_n$ and rate $I(x)$ if the following holds for any measurable $A$:
$$\limsup\frac{1}{a_n}\log\mu_n(A)\leq -\inf_{x\in\bar{A}}I(x),$$
$$\liminf\frac{1}{a_n}\log\mu_n(A)\geq -\inf_{x\in A^{o}}I(x).$$**

I was wondering why we need the closure and interior as upper and lower bounds here (resp.), instead of use the infimum on $A$ directly.

Comment: Basically because otherwise there is no chance for the bounds to hold. Think e.g. of Cramer's theorem with iid Bernoulli's and A the set of irrationals, to see that the lower bound will fail.